# Resize image with Codeigniter with low quality

Tags: codeigniter, resize-image

I am using CodeIgniter to resize image, but the small image I have resized is low quality.
Here is my code:

```
$config = array(
    'image_library' => 'gd2',
    'quality' => '100',
    'source_image' => $temp_full_path,
    'new_image' => $full_temp_path."img_mobile/",
    'maintain_ratio' => true,
    'create_thumb' => false,
    'width' => 50,
    'height' => 50
);              
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);              
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

How can make resize image with high quality like it's original image?

Here is original image, image resize generate from php code and image resize generate from codeigniter: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk8r9.jpg)

Comment: i want to make resize image with high quality?

Comment: what do you mean by low quality..it will only resize your original image. May be you are zooming the re-sized image.

Comment: You can check image below the post

Comment: @user1751978 can you `echo function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor');` and tell us?

Comment: it's return 1, mean that it's exist

Comment: What is your input and output image format? If JPEG to JPEG, then you will lose visual quality even at quality 100, since JPG is a a lossy compression. Also are you resizing? If so, making the output larger or smaller. You can try in Imagemagick, to use a different resizing filter. see https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/ and https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, GD2 doesn't use the "quality" parameter.

But some of the other libraries do use it.

Give [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `'quality' => '100%'` instead of only `'100'`

Answer (score 0):

**Default:**

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
```

**Alternative:**

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd';
$config['quality']       = 100;
```

**Best Quality:**

```
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick'; 
$config['library_path']  = "/usr/bin"; 
$config['quality']       = 100;
```

[image: Codeigniter Image Quality]

Ref: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-17374.html

Answer (score -1):

It's a small mistake or a pitfall.

Do:

```
'quality' => '100%',
```

instead of

```
'quality' => '100',
```

Should work, according to [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html).

EDIT:

There seems to be another typo!

```
'maintain_ration'
```

should be

```
'maintain_ratio'
```

Also, how can `new_image` end with a `/`? you are doing something wrong there.

Comment: 'quality' => '100%' and 'quality' => '100' are the same and change to 'maintain_ratio' but it's still not work

Comment: there is not change in quality